# Replace one element of a column in another

Tags: matlab, matrix, replace, element, diagonal

Let `A` and `B` be column vectors:

```
A = (1:6).';  %'// [1;2;3;4;5;6]   
B = (7:12).'; %'// [7;8;9;10;11;12]
```

1. How do I construct a matrix such that one element of `A` is replaced each time by an element from `B` to get `C` as:

   ```
   C = [... 
   7   1   1   1   1   1
   2   8   2   2   2   2
   3   3   9   3   3   3
   4   4   4   10  4   4
   5   5   5   5   11  5
   6   6   6   6   6   12];
   ```
2. If `C` is to be indexed as `index = [1 1 1 2 2 3 3]'`, how is it possible to produce

   ```
   c1 = [...
   1   7   1   1
   1   2   8   2
   1   3   3   9];

   c2 = [...
   2   10  4
   2   5   11]; 

   c3 = [3 6];  %// either this
   c3 = [3 12]; %// or this
   ```

Comment: Isn't `c1` supposed to be `[1 1 1; `**`7 2 3`**`; 1 8 3; 1 2 9]` ? Also I don't understand how you got `c3` at all...

Comment: @Dev-iL, you are right I corrected that, thx :)

Comment: I see that you have also updated `c3` to exclude the `NaN` s. However, I believe this vector is wrong now as much as it was before your edit.. It needs to have a 12 instead of a 6 (see my answer). Either that or I completely misunderstood how to get it... In which case please explain how you mean to get `c3`.

Comment: @Dev-iL, because there is one obs (6) in A in the last row, there is no need to swap but its ok if a swap with be occurs as well, doesnt matter for what am after. Also, I tried solving this problems earlier but what caused me issues is the size of A and B (1e6x1 each) that result in out of memory problem. I do however appreciate your input its impressing.

Comment: Out of memory problems are a completely different issue. It could be wise to ask about OOM once you have a working algorithm to produce the matrices you need (which is the answer to the current question). Also you will need to show what you tried already. As a 1st step you can try increasing the java heap memory.

Answer (score 2):

#### Problem #1:

```
C = bsxfun(@plus,A.',-diag(A)+diag(B));
```

gives:

```
 7     2     3     4     5     6
 1     8     3     4     5     6
 1     2     9     4     5     6
 1     2     3    10     5     6
 1     2     3     4    11     6
 1     2     3     4     5    12
```

#### Problem #2:

As far as I understand, you want to extract blocks out of the previously found `C` matrix, in the following fashion:

[image: Desired output (?)]

Where `c1`, `c2`, `c3` are the green, red and blue blocks, repectively; and "missing" elements are replaced with `NaN` (in the initial version of your question).

```
index = [1 1 1 2 2 3 3]; %// Block definition
[blkSz,~] = histcounts(index,numel(unique(index))); %// Conversion...
paddedC = padarray(C,numel(index)-numel(diag(C))*[1 1],NaN,'post');
blocks = mat2cell(paddedC,blkSz,blkSz);
```

This results in a cell-array `blocks` with the following contents:

```
blocks = 

    [3x3 double]    [3x2 double]    [3x2 double]
    [2x3 double]    [2x2 double]    [2x2 double]
    [2x3 double]    [2x2 double]    [2x2 double]
```

Where for example `blocks{1,1}` is:

```
ans =

     7     2     3
     1     8     3
     1     2     9
```

Then you can pad the array using the index of the loop, to get the `c` **`cell`**, like so:

```
c = cell(numel(blkSz),1); %// Preallocation
for ind1 = 1:numel(blkSz)
  c{ind1} = padarray(blocks{ind1,ind1},1,ind1,'pre');
end
```

Note that `c1` is found in `c{1}` etc.

**Addition:**

In the case when you don't want `c1...c3` to be (possibly) padded with NaNs, the best way in my opinion would be trimming the index vector to the length of `A` or `B` ("`length(C)`"). This ensures you won't access blocks outside your square matrix. For example:

```
newIdx = index(1:numel(A));
```

Then just use `newIdx` instead of `index` in the rest of the code.

Comment: awesome answer to problem #1!

Comment: @ Dev-iL could 'diag' be replaced with any other matlab function that takes in negative numbers and decimals...? thx

Comment: It can be replaced by anything that produces a matrix the size of `C` (for `bsxfun` to work).

Comment: diag is ok but I am getting ??? Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals on acutal data

Comment: @Jessi You're not going to change this question again once I answer it, are you? Looks like your original problem is solved, isn't it? As for the usage of `diag` or out-of-memory problems, that would be a **[different question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions "at Stack Exchange sites, “chameleon questions” are not quite welcome")**, consider posting it separately.